# QUERY ignoring results from IF/THEN

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm getting empty results and shouldn't be. Not sure if it is because the result in the condition column is from if/then or why. I tried formatting as text, which there's no number so data type shouldn't be a problem. I've tried `=`, `MATCHES`, `CONTAINS`, no joy.

Query is in `K2`.

`=QUERY(B2:I,"SELECT B WHERE H = 'ACH'",0)`

Here's a sample sheet. I cannot figure out why I'm getting no results.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IPZDIyJu-CRbXtL3V8QAmqADpDziyzWeZ2Kce3-kw1Q/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance. I'm under a time crunch so will probably go through by hand (actual data is more) but would like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is found in your formulae is column `H`

Delete all of them and replace them with this single formula in cell `H2`

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",, IF(D2:D="EXC",IF(F2:F="EXC","EXC"),
                       IF((D2:D="ACH")+(D2:D="EXC"),
                          IF((F2:F="ACH")+(F2:F="EXC"),"ACH"),"FALSE"))))
```

Following that your `QUERY` will work.

[image]

The way you construct your formulae now, they produce the boolean result FALSE instead of the text `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Google sheet query function treat data type of a column based on maximum number of value's data type. So, in your case `H Column` is treating as Boolean data and that is cause to get empty result. You can try to convert them to string first then use `QUERY()` function. Try-

```
=QUERY(HSTACK(B2:G,INDEX(H2:H&"")),"select Col1 where Col7='ACH'",0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it might be data type but couldn't figure it out.